# A way How to Compile C library into .Net dll?

Tags: .net, c++, c, visual-studio, clr

Can we compile C library as .Net dll (containing and opening access to all C libs functions) by just compiling cpp project containing code like

```
extern "C" {
#include <library.h>
}
```

with `/clr:pure` argument with VS? (VS10)

Or we should do something more trickey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it is the best to use the old style Managed C++ for this.

`CLR:PURE` just wont cut it.

Example:

```
extern "C" int _foo(int bar)
{
  return bar;
}

namespace Bar
{
  public __gc class Foo
  {
  public:
    Foo() {}

    static int foo(int bar)
    {
      return _foo(bar);
    }
  };
};
```

Compile with: `/clr:oldSyntax`

Now you can reference the assebmly, and call `Bar.Foo.foo()` from .NET.

Comment: What do you mean by it - please provide simple samle?

Comment: could you explain what '__gc ' is, how will this code compile into .net dll (I mean what will we acsess in it and how?)

Comment: @Ole Jak: `__gc` just indicate that this is a managed class, part of the old style syntax. You can view that in Reflector. Will be an internal class called `Foo` in the 'module' namespace.

Comment: @Ole Jak: I added a namespace and made it public, so it can be tested easier.

Comment: I like your answer - it is a ~relevantly fast and easy way of creating .Net librarys from pure C code thru C++ code using Visual studio tools. gonna try it as soon as possible. thank you very much!

Comment: I love your technique, but I wonder how to use it for more or less complex C structures and pointers? So I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239090/ Could  you please give an answer?

Comment: Don't try to make the existing code publicly visible, just get it to compile.  Then write a handful of functions in C++/CLI (avoid oldSyntax as a rule of thumb, but especially if you plan to use ILMerge) that implement the high-level tasks of your application using the x.264 library.  These can call into the C library functions just as easily as native C++ can.

Comment: @leppie After all, could you please at least give some notes on stackoverflow.com/questions/3239090 there is  bounty  btw=)

Answer (score 4):

This may be of interest to you: [Compiling your C code to .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1128868/Compiling-your-C-code-to-NET)

Create a C compiler occil.exe

To create a .NET dll from a c code e.g stack.c

Step1: build stack.c to IL code

```
occil /ostackdll.il /c /Wd /9 /NStackLib.Stack stack.c
```

Step2: build to generated IL code to .NET DLL

```
ilasm /DLL stackdll.il
```

Then you can *reference the stack.dll* in a c# program and call the C function in stack.c

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your C code.

P/Invoke is often the easiest to start with, and IMO is pretty workable for a handful of functions. Performance isn't necessarily great, and I wouldn't construct an entire program out of it - but to reuse some functions, it's worthwhile.

Going from C to /clr:pure requires you to:

1. [Convert your C code to C++](http://www.bleading-edge.com/Publications/C++Report/v9507/Article1.htm)
2. [Convert your C++ code to Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177253(v=VS.80).aspx)
3. [Compile with /clr option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173265.aspx)
4. [Compile with /clr:pure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85344whh.aspx)

The current state of your code (and it's libraries) will dictate how painful that process is.

Comment: "thay"  say you do not need P/Invoke to use .Net dll. "thay" say you can compile C++ (CPP files) code into .Net dll using 'clr:pure' argument with VS.

Comment: @Ole - "They" are correct. It's getting to that point from C which is likely to give you fits.

Comment: In his other (I've lost count, maybe five) questions about this, Ole set a requirement that everything compile into a single file.  `DllImport` won't get you there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally a given that you can even compile C code as C++ without making some changes.   If you can get your C code to compile as C++, then you can try getting it to compile as C++/CLI (that's what the clr:pure option does).

At that point, you can create some kind of class which exposes all your exported functions as static methods of a public (managed) class.

Some flavours of this sort of stuff can be done with C++ preprocessor tricks (macros, etc), sometimes you end-up writing wrappers manually.

So the basic information that you can compile C++ into .NET assemblies using /clr:xxx options is true, but that doesn't mean it's the only thing you need to do to get a useful .NET assembly.

Comment: are out there any step by step tuts or stories of sucsess in blog articles or something like that?