# How to document functions in described technique of creating C++ .Net dll's?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dll

So here we have a [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235916/a-way-how-to-compile-c-library-into-net-dll/3236027#3236027), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239090/how-you-use-technique-described-to-work-with-c-structures-and-pointers-from-ne) some more on it, of creating C++ DLLs with functions readable by .Net languages such as C#.

The main Idea of technique as I use it (I can be ideologically wrong but it totally works for me) - you created a C++ project, it worked, now you want to use some of its functions from C# (for example you keep logik in C and create a gui in C#, so in C# you can be just calling only one main function of ex consol C++ app turned into library)

I like this so called old-style of creating managed parts in C++  code.

So I wonder how to describe (document) C++ functions so that description will be seen in C#?

Let us look at an example (Compile with: /clr:oldSyntax)

```
 extern "C" int _foo(int bar)
{
  return bar;
}

namespace Bar
{
  public __gc class Foo
  {
  public:
    Foo() {}

    static int foo(int bar)
    {
      return _foo(bar);
    }
  };
};
```

How can I document our foo function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoah... you are using old style Managed C++ with the `__gc` business. You should instead use C++/CLI where you will say `public ref class Foo`. You can then use the same Doc Comments (starting with `///` and having XML in them) as you would in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a .dll in C# to wrap it and add the documentation to that.

Comment: It would be write from some point but than I'd have a project structure like initialCPPLib, C#LibWrapper, C#App instead of just initialCPPLib and C#App... so my point is that I'd have +1 layer of depth and +1 project just for documentation... while I'd love to be able to create documentation directly in C++ code